# how can i run e2e tests with karma ( & karma-e2e-dsl ) on production ( without angular )

Tags: testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, ui-testing, e2e-testing

I want to write automated e2e tests with karma for a remote site.

I created the karma.config file and it connects to my local browsers with ease.

Now i woudl like to write this test for a site that is not on my pc.(eg google.com ).
How could i do that?

I am using karma-e2e-dsl ( https://github.com/winsonwq/karma-e2e-dsl )
& Mocha.For now my test is running but the frame is empty.

test:

```
browser.navigateTo('http://google.pl');
```

config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['mocha','karma-e2e-dsl'],
files: [
  'tests/google/1.js'
],
exclude: [],
preprocessors: {
},
reporters: ['progress'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Firefox'],
singleRun: false,
concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```